# DNN model - strange results. "Loss" results different in Train/Testing and in Kaggle

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras, theano, conv-neural-network

I have trained a simple DNN model - using Keras with Theano backend, having:
 2 * (3x3 conv layer, 2x2 max-pool, 15% dropout), 
 96-FC layer,
 softmax activation on the final layer,
 optimizer: adam.
The goal was to perform a classification into 6 classes.
I have a dataset which consist of 116000 equally distributed among all classes images.
After 14 epochs - the validation results were great:
loss: 0.1,  accuracy 92% on a test data  - and during the training I had a similar results on my training and validation data.

The task is for learning purpose only - defined in Kaggle website. They want a minimum log-loss result.  When I upload my predictions there - the calculated loss is very high ( > 2)

Do you have any suggestions?

some code representing the network and how I use it:

## 1. Inputs:

116000 images of size 160x160

## 2. Model

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(1, 160, 160)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))

model.add(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.15))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(96, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(classes), activation='softmax'))
```

## 3. Compile and fit:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',#categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(np.array(trainData[0]), np.array(trainData[1]), 
          batch_size=13, nb_epoch=14, verbose=1, shuffle=True, callbacks=callbacks_list, validation_data = (np.array(validationData[0]), np.array(validationData[1])))
```

## 4. Test with a new set of samples:

```
scores = model.evaluate(np.array(testData[0]), np.array(testData[1]), verbose=1)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order for others to be able to help you, please check 'How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example' https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added more info.

Comment: Could you add that "Kaggle" reference? As @desertnaut mentioned, you should check that link. Not necessarily adding *more* stuff to you question makes it better... it usually is the opposite. Make sure it is Minimal and Complete